# Julia- Make Array{Float64,3} in a short time

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

I want to get Array{Float64,3} from a matrix-valued function H(Lx,Ly,Lz) ,where Lx,Ly,Lz are parameters and H is a (Lx×Ly×Lz)×(Lx×Ly×Lz) matrix.

The sample code is

```
using LinearAlgebra
eye(T::Type,n) = Diagonal{T}(I, n) 
eye(n) = eye(Float64,n)

function H(Lx,Ly,Lz) #def of H
N = Lx*Ly*Lz　

　mat_Htb = zeros(Complex{Float64},N,N) 

　for iz = 1:Lz
    　for ix = 1:Lx
        　for iy=1:Ly             
            　for dz in -1:1             
            　jz = iz + dz 
                　for dx in -1:1
                　jx = ix + dx
                    　for dy in -1:1
                     　jy = iy + dy
                        
                            　ii = (iz-1)*Lx*Ly + (ix-1)*Ly + (iy-1) + 1
                            　jj = (jz-1)*Lx*Ly + (jx-1)*Ly + (jy-1) + 1

                                　if 1 <= jx <= Lx && 1 <= jy <= Ly && 1 <= jz <= Lz
                                     
                                    　if dx == +1 && dy == 0 && dz == 0
                                        　mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im 　
                                    　end
                            
                                    　if dx == -1 && dy == 0 && dz == 0 
                                        　mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im/4 　
                                    　end
                        
                                    　if dx == 0 && dy == +1 && dz == 0 
                                        　mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im/2
                                    　end
                            
                                    　if dx == 0 && dy == -1 && dz == 0 
                                        　mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im
                                    　end
                        
                                    　if dx == 0 && dy == 0 && dz == +1 
                                        　mat_Htb[ii,jj] += -im
                                    　end
                                      
                                    　if dx == 0 && dy == 0 && dz == -1 
                                        　mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im*(3/7)
                                    　end
                                    
                                    　if dx == 0 && dy == 0 && dz == 0 
                                        　mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im
                                    　end
                                     
                        　end
                    　end
                　end
            　end
        　end
    　end
　end
                
    
　return mat_Htb
end


Lx = 10 #systemsize-parameters
Ly = 10
Lz = 10


ψ0 = Complex{Float64}[] #def of \psi0 ,(Lx×Ly×Lz)×1 vector

for iz = 1:Lz
    for ix = 1:Lx
        for iy=1:Ly         
            gauss = exp(-((ix-5)^2 + (iy-5)^2 + (iz-5)^2))
            push!(ψ0,gauss)
        end
    end
end

ψ(t) = exp((-im*t).*H(Lx,Ly,Lz))*ψ0 #time-evolution
abs2ψ(t) = abs2.(ψ(t)./norm(ψ(t))) #normalized density
```

Then, I tried to make an Array{Float64,3} like this.

```
x = 1:Lx  # our value range
y = 1:Ly
z = 1:Lz
t = 15 #time

ρ(ix,iy,iz) = abs2ψ(t)[(iz-1)*Lx*Ly + (ix-1)*Ly + (iy-1) + 1] 
density = Float64[ρ(ix,iy,iz) for ix in x, iy in y,iz in z]
```

H(Lx,Ly,Lz),ψ(t),abs2ψ(t),ρ(ix,iy,iz) are calculated smoothly.
But the density takes about 30 minutes.

Ultimately, I will do loop-calculations for t.
So I want to reduce the calculation time.
Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: It would be better if you copy a minimal reproducible example, i.e. writing code that one can run, including the definitions of H and psi. One thing I could note, though, is that you should pass Lx,Ly,Lz,t and psi also as arguments to your function. This way the compiler will be able to generate efficient code.

Comment: As you said, my question is too abstract. I edited it.

Comment: I think this problem comes from repeated calculations of exp((-im*t).*H(Lx,Ly,Lz)) for each (ix,iy,iz). But I don't know the solution.

Comment: Hint: whenever `H(Lx,Ly,Lz)` is called, `mat_Htb = zeros(Complex{Float64},N,N)` will trigger huge memory allocations if `N` is large.

Comment: Is there a method to avoid calling H(Lx,Ly,Lz) multiple times? or Is it inevitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still numerous things that would probably need to be improved, but the following version should already be much faster than yours.

The key thing to remember is to try and not recompute the same thing several times (especially if it takes some time to compute it, and you're going to re-use the result a large number of times).

In your example, this applies to :

- `H`, which only depends on `Lx`, `Ly` and `Lz`, and as such can be computed once and for all
- `ψ` and `abs2ψ`, which depend on `H` and `t`, and should therefore get updated at each time step -- but can be re-used for all `(ix, iy, iz)` triplets.

```
using LinearAlgebra

function H(Lx,Ly,Lz)
    N = Lx*Ly*Lz　

    mat_Htb = zeros(Complex{Float64},N,N)

    for iz = 1:Lz
        for ix = 1:Lx
            for iy=1:Ly
                for dz in -1:1
                    jz = iz + dz
                    for dx in -1:1
                        jx = ix + dx
                        for dy in -1:1
                            jy = iy + dy

                            ii = (iz-1)*Lx*Ly + (ix-1)*Ly + (iy-1) + 1
                            jj = (jz-1)*Lx*Ly + (jx-1)*Ly + (jy-1) + 1

                            if 1 <= jx <= Lx && 1 <= jy <= Ly && 1 <= jz <= Lz

                                if dx == +1 && dy == 0 && dz == 0
                                    mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im
                                end

                                if dx == -1 && dy == 0 && dz == 0
                                    mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im/4
                                end

                                if dx == 0 && dy == +1 && dz == 0
                                    mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im/2
                                end

                                if dx == 0 && dy == -1 && dz == 0
                                    mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im
                                end

                                if dx == 0 && dy == 0 && dz == +1
                                    mat_Htb[ii,jj] += -im
                                end

                                if dx == 0 && dy == 0 && dz == -1
                                    mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im*(3/7)
                                end

                                if dx == 0 && dy == 0 && dz == 0
                                    mat_Htb[ii,jj] += im
                                end

                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    return mat_Htb
end


function run(Lx, Ly, Lz)
    ψ0 = Complex{Float64}[] #def of \psi0 ,(Lx×Ly×Lz)×1 vector

    for iz = 1:Lz
        for ix = 1:Lx
            for iy=1:Ly
                gauss = exp(-((ix-5)^2 + (iy-5)^2 + (iz-5)^2))
                push!(ψ0,gauss)
            end
        end
    end

    x = 1:Lx  # our value range
    y = 1:Ly
    z = 1:Lz
    t = 15 #time

    H_ = H(Lx,Ly,Lz)
    ψ = exp((-im*t).*H_)*ψ0 #time-evolution
    abs2ψ = abs2.(ψ./norm(ψ)) #normalized density

    ρ(ix,iy,iz) = abs2ψ[(iz-1)*Lx*Ly + (ix-1)*Ly + (iy-1) + 1]
    density = Float64[ρ(ix,iy,iz) for ix in x, iy in y,iz in z]
end

Lx = 10 #systemsize-parameters
Ly = 10
Lz = 10
run(Lx, Ly, Lz)
```

---

For questions like this, which are very specific to a code that you want to optimize, I tend to think that posting on [Julia's discourse forum](https://discourse.julialang.org) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! I'll never forget that idea.